# PO file problem 1 error nowhere to be found and issues in header

Tags: translation, po, poedit

I am currently editing a PO translation file which is driving me nuts. Every time i save the file in poedit i get this message: "1 issue with the translation found", followed by the default text about the entries that contain the error are marked red. The problem is however, nothing is marked red, not a single entry.

After that initial error another error message follows: "warning header field 'Last-Translator' still has the default initial default value". I don't know what this means. I have compared the properties of the file to other po files and can not seem to find anything wrong with it.

I have been trying all kind of things for hours now, i can't get the file fixed. Maybe someone here has more experience with these files and can help me out?

BTW: The translation partially works, with some entries being translated while others are not.

Link to the file: [enter link description here](https://www48.zippyshare.com/v/WAAgcFNC/file.html)